# unknown SQL average queries in logs Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

Evening all,

I just had a quick question about SQL average queries.

I have a post model which has many ratings. All of the ratings for a particular post are added up and divided by the number of ratings for the average. So this calculation is declared in the post model and saved in the database. In my index view I list out all of the posts, with their author, name and their rating, which comes from the post rating db column.

My question is, why is rails performing all of these SQL average queries when these values have been saved in the database?

my code is as follows:

In the console

```
Post Load (1.0ms)  SELECT `posts`.* FROM `posts` ORDER BY posts.created_at ASC LIMIT 1
 => #<Post id: 48, user_id: 5, song_name: "Enter Sandman", song: "ewwe wer ere rr erew rewr r erw erw rewedwde", created_at: "2012-08-16 13:35:32", updated_at: "2012-08-22 21:11:34", rating: 5.0, ratings_count: 2>
```

Post.rb

```
def rating
    if self.ratings.any?
      self.rating = self.ratings.average(:rating)
    end
  end
```

posts/index.html.erb

```
<legend>Music library</legend>  

    <%= will_paginate @paginate_posts %>

            <% if @paginate_posts.any? %>
                <% @paginate_posts.each do |post| %>
            <h4><%= link_to post.song_name, post %></h4>
                Author: <%= link_to post.user.name, "#" %><br/>
                    <% if post.rating == nil %>
                        No one has rated this yet<br/>
                    <% else %>
                        Rating: <%= post.rating %>/10<br/>
                    <% end %>
                <br/>
        <% end %>
<% end %>

<%= will_paginate @paginate_posts %>
```

posts_controller.rb index action (I've tried eager loading but the avg queries are still there)

```
def index
    @paginate_posts = Post.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 10).includes(:user).search(params[:search])
  end
```

SQL logs with lots of queries

```
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-08-22 22:51:38 +0100
Processing by PostsController#index as HTML
  Post Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `posts`.* FROM `posts` ORDER BY posts.created_at DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` IN (5)
   (0.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `posts` 
  Rendered posts/_copy.html.erb (0.1ms)
   (0.3ms)  SELECT AVG(`ratings`.`rating`) AS avg_id FROM `ratings` WHERE `ratings`.`post_id` = 63
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT AVG(`ratings`.`rating`) AS avg_id FROM `ratings` WHERE `ratings`.`post_id` = 63
   (0.3ms)  SELECT AVG(`ratings`.`rating`) AS avg_id FROM `ratings` WHERE `ratings`.`post_id` = 62
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT AVG(`ratings`.`rating`) AS avg_id FROM `ratings` WHERE `ratings`.`post_id` = 62
   (0.2ms)  SELECT AVG(`ratings`.`rating`) AS avg_id FROM `ratings` WHERE `ratings`.`post_id` = 61
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT AVG(`ratings`.`rating`) AS avg_id FROM `ratings` WHERE `ratings`.`post_id` = 61
   (0.2ms)  SELECT AVG(`ratings`.`rating`) AS avg_id FROM `ratings` WHERE `ratings`.`post_id` = 60
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT AVG(`ratings`.`rating`) AS avg_id FROM `ratings` WHERE `ratings`.`post_id` = 60
   (0.2ms)  SELECT AVG(`ratings`.`rating`) AS avg_id FROM `ratings` WHERE `ratings`.`post_id` = 59
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT AVG(`ratings`.`rating`) AS avg_id FROM `ratings` WHERE `ratings`.`post_id` = 59
   (0.2ms)  SELECT AVG(`ratings`.`rating`) AS avg_id FROM `ratings` WHERE `ratings`.`post_id` = 58
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT AVG(`ratings`.`rating`) AS avg_id FROM `ratings` WHERE `ratings`.`post_id` = 58
   (0.2ms)  SELECT AVG(`ratings`.`rating`) AS avg_id FROM `ratings` WHERE `ratings`.`post_id` = 57
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT AVG(`ratings`.`rating`) AS avg_id FROM `ratings` WHERE `ratings`.`post_id` = 57
   (0.2ms)  SELECT AVG(`ratings`.`rating`) AS avg_id FROM `ratings` WHERE `ratings`.`post_id` = 56
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT AVG(`ratings`.`rating`) AS avg_id FROM `ratings` WHERE `ratings`.`post_id` = 56
   (0.2ms)  SELECT AVG(`ratings`.`rating`) AS avg_id FROM `ratings` WHERE `ratings`.`post_id` = 55
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT AVG(`ratings`.`rating`) AS avg_id FROM `ratings` WHERE `ratings`.`post_id` = 55
   (0.3ms)  SELECT AVG(`ratings`.`rating`) AS avg_id FROM `ratings` WHERE `ratings`.`post_id` = 54
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT AVG(`ratings`.`rating`) AS avg_id FROM `ratings` WHERE `ratings`.`post_id` = 54
  Rendered posts/index.html.erb within layouts/application (60.8ms)
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 5 LIMIT 1
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 2012ms (Views: 1871.7ms | ActiveRecord: 33.1ms)
```

as usual if you need more code just shout.
many thanks, Andy

Comment: What makes you think that "these values have been saved in the database" is true?

Comment: hmmm, good point, Ive updated my answer with info from the console when retrieving a post. It seems to have the rating saved as 5.0? is this not the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a method called rating here in post which overrides the accessor on your model, so even if you have a db column 'rating' it's not going to be called when you ask for model.rating, the method will be, which will iterate ratings again. In addition the method is not saving (just setting an attribute does not persist to the db, you need to call save or similar). So if you want to save the value in rating, I'd get rid of that method.

You should really do this when the post has a rating added or is changed - at that point, call update_rating or something (see below), and then make sure you are calling post.save after (either make it a before_save callback, or call self.update_attribute or self.save explitly in update_rating) - that will save the change to the db, and then you can use

```
<%= post.rating %>
```

in views or anywhere else as a cached average rating value.

in Post model:

```
before_save :update_rating

def update_rating
  if self.ratings.any?
    self.rating = self.ratings.average(:rating)
  end
end
```

Comment: Hi Kenny, I didn't know that a method name could overide the accessor in a model, brilliant!! thank you! Andy

Answer (score 1):

Your looping over your posts. Within each loop you call:

```
post.rating
```

which in turn fires of your AVG SQL query:

```
self.ratings.average(:rating)
```

Its not saved, it just computed so your 'if post.rating = ' works

Comment: Hi Rogier, I've fettled with a few things, but overall not sure how to address this correctly, how could i save this to the database? many thanks

Comment: why would you like to save it? i can imagine, that the ratings are changing (i.e. more posts), so  self.ratings.average(:rating) gives you always the latest (and most accurate) rating.

Comment: I would like to save the average so that, when i iterate over the posts to get their ratings, its not performing loads of timely sql queries, now its ok as there aren't many songs but when there are a few hundred it will be a bit of a pain.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience I've found that @Kenny-Grant's `update_rating` method won't actually include newly added ratings in the average when calculating and persisting the updated rating.

This has worked for me:

```
after_save :update_rating!

def update_rating
  self.rating = ratings.average(:rating) || 0.0
end

def update_rating!
  self.update_columns(rating: update_score)
end
```

This make sure that the newly added records show up, since `ratings` is a call to the DB, not in memory at this stage. `update_columns` lets you rewrite the record without causing an extra `save` action which would trigger all its callbacks. Using the `update_rating` method when writing the column also sets the in-memory rating attribute, which `update_columns` would not do unless you also reloaded the model afterward.